# Angular Validation Required Field CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

In the Angular.js library, I would like to know where the CSS comes from that creates the following hovering required field validation.

[image]

When I try to inspect this element in Chrome, the hovering element disappears and I'm not able to inspect it.

Comment: for remove this validation use this <form novalidate>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not Angular validation, it's the browser.

Add the novalidate attribute to the form tag - this suppresses the default browser validation. Then use [ng-messages](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMessages/directive/ngMessages) or [ng-if](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngIf) to show your own validation.